# multiple system trays like virtual desktops?

Tags: windows-xp, notification-area, virtual-desktop

there's software to give virtual desktops.. programs like virtual dimension, or virtuwin.

but what about a program to give each desktop its own system tray?

Comment: a correction to what I wrote.. I think the virtual desktop concept isn't really it , the programs are more limited than that, just giving more like a bunch of screense each with the same desktop icons, but a new taskbar(though same system tray and same quicklaunch). So the new screen is just the same just with no windows open.

Answer (score 0):

I know it runs from the system tray, but does Sysinternals Desktops run multiple system trays?  I download their suite, but never use this.  I am just reaching here.  Also, you might want to start looking into custom Windows shells GUIs.  I have used LiteStep professionally, and the [system tray add-ons](http://lsdocs.shellfront.org/systray.php) are meant to be highly customizable.  I will not lie though.  You would need to go to a website like customize.org or similar to ask if this functionality is possible.  If you have teh hax0r C++ skills, you could definitely extend it to do so.  It is open source.  I am not sure if this is an intentional OS limitation in Windows though.  Sorry, I am very unsure.